# Why vi doesn't show syntax highlighting when create script

Tags: linux, vi

When I use vi to create a script, it doesn't show any syntax highlighting. But once I exit vi and use vi to open the script again, It will highlight the syntax.
What I want is to highlight the syntax for the first time when I create the file. So is there anything wrong with my configuration or it is the common situation?

Comment: please post the  "vi --version" command output.

Comment: Are you using `vi` or `vim` and what is your configuration?

Comment: Make sure `filetype` is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When vim opens a file, it tries to guess the file type in order to enable syntax highlighting. When you open a new file called "myscript", vim has nothing to go on in order to guess the type.

When you write the file, the first file you write is `#!/bin/sh` (or similar), followed by the rest of the script. By this point, vim has already determined this is a plain text file, and does not syntax highlighting.

When you reopen the file, vim sees the first line of the file, and understands this is a shell script. It sets the type appropriately, and does syntax magic.

In order to solve, either name the file with an extension that suggests its type (an empty file called "myscript.sh" is, likely, a shell script), or manually set the type using `:set filetype=sh`

Personally, I find the first form ugly (why include the file type in the file name?), and the second one hard to remember. I just close and reopen the file :-)

Answer (score 0):

vi usually guess the kind of syntax highlighting to use from the filename extension. If you're editing a file that doesn't yet have a name, you will need to tell it how to highlight:

`:set filetype=html`

Comment: After I add the .sh as the extension. it is now highlighting the syntax. Thanks!!